# Using await for request and 'if' implementation

Tags: node.js

I see the below code in my application. I am not able to understand the logic implemented.
Can someone explain me how the below works. Is this a different implementation of 'if' condition.
Also, Can I put 'await' ahead of 'request' in the below code since I need to wait till I get response for this request made. If not, how else can I use await below.

```
newstatus != undefined &&
request(params, (error, response, body) => {
    error && console.info("error");
    console.info("response received:", body);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript this && operator named as AND
&& means if a condition returns true then move to the next step otherwise not go for the next inner step.

```
newstatus != undefined &&
  request(params, (error, response, body) => {
    error && console.info("error");
    console.info("response received:", body);
  });
```

the above example demonstrates that if(newstatus != undefined) condition true then call request API call.

To answer your second question how can we use async in it.
await use for promises only or before functions that return promise after completing some tasks like API call.

you have to make a function for request API that return Promise
here we have created the doRequest() function that will return a promise.

solution:

```
function doRequest(url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request(params, (error, response, body) => {
      if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
        resolve(body);
      } else {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}


// Usage:

async function main() {
  let res = await doRequest(url);
  console.log(res);
}

         OR 

newstatus != undefined && await doRequest(url);
```

Comment: I have 2 asynchronous functions abc  and xyz called inside request method (request-promise). How can ensure these methods get executed sequentially?                                                
function exam(){ 
console.log('st1');
 request(params, (err,res,body) => {
    abc();
    xyz();
 }
 );
console.log('st2');
}
async function abc()
{
 API call //async statements
 console.log('ABC');
}
async function xyz()
{
 API call //async statements
 console.log('XYZ');
}
My final output should be in the order:
st1
ABC
XYZ
st2

Comment: functionexam(){console.log("st1");request(url,async(error,res,body)=>{if(!error&&res.statusCode==200){awaitabc();awaitxyz();console.log("st2");resolve(body);}else{reject(error);}});}functionabc(){returnnewPromise((resolve,reject)=>{request(url,(error,res,body)=>{if(!error&&res.statusCode==200){console.log("ABC");resolve(body);}else{reject(error);}});});}functionxyz(){returnnewPromise(async(resolve,reject)=>{request(url,(error,res,body)=>{if(!error&&res.statusCode==200){console.log("XYZ");resolve(body);}else{reject(error);}});});}/*output:st1ABCXYZst2*/